# How to print excel to PDF excluding the first sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to print an excel work book as a pdf but exclude the first sheet entitled basic Information from the PDF. At the moment the whole work book is being included in the PDF.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePDF()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
  Dim s As Worksheet
  Dim DoNotInclude As String

  With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

  Title = "I&T Plan for " & Worksheets("Basic Information").Range("C7").Value
  PdfFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & Title & ".pdf"
  
    Sheets("Front Sheet").Select
   
  
  DoNotInclude = ("Basic Information")
  
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If s.Visible = True Then
      If InStr(DoNotInclude, s.Name) = 0 Then
          s.Select (False)
      End If
    End If
  Next

  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
  End With

  Sheets("Front Sheet").Select

  MsgBox "Created PDF file on the desktop", vbOKOnly, "I&T PDF"

  With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? It's working fine.

Comment: As stated the Basic information sheet is being included in the PDF

Answer (score 0):

Select all sheets except the first:

```vb
Dim x As Long, wb As Workbook
    
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.Sheets(2).Select
For x = 3 To Sheets.Count
    wb.Sheets(x).Select False
Next x
```

Print...

Answer (score 0):

### Export Multiple Worksheets to PDF

- Fun fact: if you select any worksheet except "Basic Information", your code will work as required. You have to take into account that the currently selected (active) sheet will end up in the selection.

To not care about which sheet is selected or the position (index) of a sheet, you can use:

```
Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
Dim n As Long
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If s.Visible = True Then
    If InStr(1, DoNotInclude, s.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        n = n + 1
        arr(n) = s.Name
    End If
  End If
Next
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To n)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(arr).Select
```

between the lines:

```
DoNotInclude = "Basic Information"
```

and

```
With ActiveSheet
```

Comment: Thanks - that works perfetly. funnily enough th ecode was copied from another workbook and works fine